# I can't seem to get my media query to work for responsive site

Tags: css, html, media-queries

Forgive me, as I'm new to CSS and web development all together. I have the viewport meta tag, and I have the media query in a separate css file. I've looked over my code, and there aren't any style changes in the HTML doc, and I don't see any in style.css that should override. I can't seem to find my error.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/responsive.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

//responsive.css

```
@media (max-width: 768){  
    body{  
    display:none;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, click the checkmark next to the correct answer. If not, leave a comment below the answers elaborating on what is missing or unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the unit `px`:

```
@media (max-width: 768)
```

must be

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid I over looked. Thank you so much!